# Strange time in received sms

Tags: android, xamarin, sms

When I send myself sms message and add it to history (before receiving) by next code

```
private void AddSentSmsToHistory(String address, String message) 
        {
            try {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.Put("address", address);
                values.Put("body", message);
                //values.Put("date", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
                //getContentResolver.Insert(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
                ContentResolver.Insert(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, String.Format("SMS cannot be stored, becasue '{0}'", e.Message), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
```

history shows next "sent 17:58" and received "**01:02**" with date "**Mar 30 265688**"

**update 1**:

1. sources can be found https://github.com/constructor-igor
2. allocated issue can be found https://github.com/constructor-igor/sms2/issues/16
3. uploaded screens with details of the issue

[image: screen 1]
[image: screen 2]

**update 2**:
found solution of the issue:

```
        var totalPeriod = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        long milliseconds = (long)totalPeriod.TotalMilliseconds;
        values.Put("date", milliseconds);
```

Comment: Are you parsing your time to get that string? If so where?

Comment: I don't parse: standard android history shows the strange times of received (not sent!) sms message.

Comment: so the native Android text app shows that as your received time? If so, you definitely have a head scratcher.

Comment: uploaded additional details of the issue (path to sources, screens with strange time)

Comment: found solution (see update 2 into question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found next solution of "strange" sms time:

```
        var totalPeriod = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        long milliseconds = (long)totalPeriod.TotalMilliseconds;
        values.Put("date", milliseconds);
```

Value "date" of ContentValues should contain "total milliseconds".